# Prometheus: filter query based on another metric

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana

Say I have two metrics in prometheus, both counters:

- `requests_processed_total`
- `requests_failed_total`

They both have a matching `service` label. Example:

```
requests_processed_total{service="news"} 1097
requests_processed_total{service="store"} 487
requests_failed_total{service="news"} 23
requests_failed_total{service="store"} 89
```

How to query the `requests_failed_total`, but only for services whose `request_processed_total > 1000`.

I'm expecting the following response:

```
requests_failed_total{service="news"} 23

# Note that the "store" service is excluded
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Grafana you can do the following:

(1) Create a dashboard

(2) Click on Dashboard settings > Variables > New

(3) Create a variable with the following:

```
Name        = service
Type        = Query

Data source = Prometheus
Query       = query_result(request_processed_total>5)
Regex       = /service="(.*)"/
```

(4) Use the "service" variable to show the "requests_failed_total" metrics in any panel (you can also use the "repeat for " Grafana feature.

Comment: Nice, this will do! I wish there was a built-in syntax to prometheus for this though.

Answer (score 6):

`requests_failed_total and on(service) requests_processed_total > 1000`

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTTP API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/) to do this.

The following command will find services with request_processed_total>1000:

```
curl --silent --user USER:PASS --globoff --request GET "https://PROMETHEUS-SERVER/query?query=request_processed_total>1000" | jq --raw-output '.data.result[].metric.service'
```

And the following command will show requests_failed_total for a given service:

```
curl --silent --user USER:PASS --globoff --request GET "https://PROMETHEUS-SERVER/query?query=request_failed_total{service=\"SERVICE\"}" | jq --raw-output '.data.result[].value[1]'
```

So if you take both you get what you want:

```
for s in $(curl --silent --user USER:PASS --globoff --request GET "https://PROMETHEUS-SERVER/query?query=request_processed_total>1000" | jq --raw-output '.data.result[].metric.service')
do
    curl --silent --user USER:PASS --globoff --request GET "https://PROMETHEUS-SERVER/query?query=request_failed_total{service=\"$s\"}" | jq --raw-output '.data.result[] | .metric.service + " " + .value[1]'
done
```

Comment: I guess that could be a solution, but I can't use that for two reasons: 1. it's going to make a lot of requests (lots of different label values) and 2. I'm using grafana to execute the request.

Comment: You didn't have mentioned Grafana. I added another answer using Grafana now.